# matplotlib subplots with equal aspect ratio and individual colorbars

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

I would like to draw 4 subplots with an equal aspect ratio and an individual colorbar for each subplot. I am nearly finished, but I the font is very big and the colorbars are badly positioned as they overlap with the x-axes title; see the attached code and resulting image. How to get a better result?

```
import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
data = numpy.random.random((3, 10))
fig, (ax1, ax2, ax3, ax4) = plt.subplots(nrows=4)
im1 = ax1.pcolormesh(data)
ax1.set_title('IM1')
im2 = ax2.pcolormesh(data)
ax2.set_title('IM2')
im3 = ax3.pcolormesh(data)
ax3.set_title('IM3')
im4 = ax4.pcolormesh(data)
ax4.set_title('IM4')
for ax, tc in zip((ax1, ax2, ax3, ax4), (im1, im2, im3, im4)):
    ax.tick_params(direction='out', which='both', top=True, right=True)
    ax.minorticks_on()
    ax.set_aspect('equal')
    ax.set_xlabel('$x$')
    ax.set_ylabel('$y$')
    fig.colorbar(tc, ax=ax, orientation='horizontal')
fig.tight_layout()
fig.savefig('im.png', dpi=300, bbox_inches='tight')
```

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure about the correct automatic positioning of the colorbars, but I can provide with the suggestion to specify the figure's size to make the font proportional. For example: `... plt.subplots(..., figsize=(50,10))`

Comment: I'm not sure if the decision to have the 4 subplots stacked vertically is due to some other constraint, but stopping overlapping labels etc. can be made much easier with different layouts of the subplots.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to my comment:

1. You can scale the font-size by either changing its size or by changing the size of the figure. If we do the latter you can use: `... plt.subplots(..., figsize=(50,10))`
2. You can better place the colorbar by 'attaching' it to the relevant axis.

For both points see this updated example:

```
import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable

data = numpy.random.random((3, 10))
fig, (ax1, ax2, ax3, ax4) = plt.subplots(nrows=4,figsize=(50,10))
im1 = ax1.pcolormesh(data)
ax1.set_title('IM1')
im2 = ax2.pcolormesh(data)
ax2.set_title('IM2')
im3 = ax3.pcolormesh(data)
ax3.set_title('IM3')
im4 = ax4.pcolormesh(data)
ax4.set_title('IM4')

for ax, im in zip((ax1, ax2, ax3, ax4), (im1, im2, im3, im4)):
    ax.tick_params(direction='out', which='both', top=True, right=True)
    ax.minorticks_on()
    ax.set_aspect('equal')
    ax.set_xlabel('$x$')
    ax.set_ylabel('$y$')
    div  = make_axes_locatable(ax)
    cax  = div.append_axes("bottom", size="20%", pad=0.5)
    cbar = plt.colorbar(im,cax=cax,orientation='horizontal')

fig.tight_layout()
fig.savefig('im.png', dpi=300, bbox_inches='tight')
```

Which produces the image below.

[image]

I'm only not sure about getting an automatic value to the padding. Maybe somebody else can contribute?

Comment: I think its hard to automatically adjust the padding, as it will depend also on the fontsize. But the value you chose here seems to be fine for the dafault case.

Answer (score 1):

In order to create `n` subplots with `n` horizontal colorbars (one below each axes), you can create an axes grid of `2*n` axes, where every second axes is much smaller in height. Those smaller axes can host the colorbars.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

n=4
data = np.random.random((3, 10))
ratios = np.ones(2*n)
ratios[1::2]=0.05
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2*n, figsize=(4,2*n),
                         gridspec_kw={"height_ratios":ratios})

for i,ax in enumerate(axes[::2]):
    im = ax.pcolormesh(data)
    ax.set_title('IM{}'.format(i+1))
    ax.tick_params(direction='out', which='both', top=True, right=True)
    ax.minorticks_on()
    ax.set_aspect('equal')
    ax.set_xlabel('$x$')
    ax.set_ylabel('$y$')
    fig.colorbar(im, cax=axes[2*i+1], orientation='horizontal')

fig.tight_layout()
fig.savefig('im.png', dpi=300, bbox_inches='tight')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can set font size for each element and change the position of the colorbar. This is my solution:

```
import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
data = numpy.random.random((3, 10))
fig, (ax1, ax2, ax3, ax4) = plt.subplots(nrows=4)
im1 = ax1.pcolormesh(data)
ax1.set_title('IM1', size = 3) # size arguments for font changes
im2 = ax2.pcolormesh(data)
ax2.set_title('IM2', size = 3)
im3 = ax3.pcolormesh(data)
ax3.set_title('IM3', size = 3)
im4 = ax4.pcolormesh(data)
ax4.set_title('IM4', size = 3)
for ax, tc in zip((ax1, ax2, ax3, ax4), (im1, im2, im3, im4)):
    ax.tick_params(labelsize = 3, direction='out', which='both', top=True, right=True)
    ax.minorticks_on()
    ax.set_aspect('equal')
    ax.set_xlabel('$x$', size = 3)
    ax.set_ylabel('$y$', size = 3)
    cbar = fig.colorbar(tc, ax=ax, orientation='horizontal', pad=0.5) # pad for positioning colorbar
    cbar.ax.tick_params(labelsize=2) # labelsize for colorbar
fig.tight_layout()
fig.savefig('im.png', dpi=300, bbox_inches='tight')
```

I'm not sure if it's the best way to do this but simple enough to do it quickly :) Also, you should consider the suggestion to set the size of the figure.
I hope it helps!